# Subsets of the Tychonoff cube.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the Tychonoff cube $X = I^{2^{\omega}}$, where $I = [0,1]$. In class, we saw that $X$ is separable. Would $X$ contain a dense metrizable subset as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully my proof is correct.

The Tychonoff cube $X$ will not have a dense metrizable subset. To see this, we need the following proposition.

**Proposition**  Let $X$ be regular and $A$ be a dense subset of $X$. If $A$ is first-countable at a point $x \in A$, then $X$ is first-countable at that same point $x$.

**Proof**  Let $A$ be a dense subset of a regular space $X$ and let A be first countable at the point $x$. Consider the countable local base $\{ B_n \}$ of $x$ in $A$.

Since $A \subset X$, we have $B_n = V_n \cap A$, where $V_n$ is an open subset of $X$. Therefore, $x \in \overline{B_n} = \overline{V_n \cap A} = \overline{V_n}$. (All closures are taken in $X$.)

We now show $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{B_n}) = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{V_n}) $ will form a base of $x$ in $X$.

By regularity, for any open neighborbood $O_x$ of $x$ (in $X$), we can find an open subset $O^*_x$ such that $x \subset O^{*}_x \subset \overline{O^{*}_x} \subset O_x$. Fix $n$ such that $B_n\subset O^*_x\cap A$; then $\overline{V_n}=\overline{B_n} \subset \overline{O^{*}_x} \subset O_x$, which implies that $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{B_n}) \subset O_x$.

Thus, sets of the form $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{B_n}) = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{V_n}) $ will form a base of $x$ in $X$ and the proposition is proved. $\square$

However, the Tychonoff cube does not have a countable base at any point, so $A$ could never be first-countable and hence cannot be metrizable.

Also note that for a regular space $X$, a dense subset $A$ and a base $\mathscr{B}$ for $A$,
the sets of the form $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{U})$, where $U \in \mathscr{B}$, need not form a base for $X$. For instance, if $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A = \mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathscr{B}$ is the set of all intervals in $\mathbb{Q}$ whose closure (in $\mathbb{R}$) does not contain $\sqrt{2}$, you get a counterexample. The point is that $U$ doesn't have to belong to the given base $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: I fixed a typo and improved the $\LaTeX$ a little, and while I was at it I took the liberty of making the argument a little clearer; please take a look to see whether the changes are acceptable.

Comment: I like it. Thank you Brian!

Answer (score 3):

**Added: Of course what follows is nonsense, because the metric does not generate the product topology. As the OP points out in the comments below, a dense subspace of $X$ cannot be first countable.**

It even contains a countable dense metrizable subset.

Take $J=[0,1)$ as the index set of the product, so that as a set $X$ is the set of functions from $J$ to $I$. Let $Q=\mathbb{Q}\cap I$. For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, each $(n+1)$-tuple $\bar q=\langle q_1,\dots,q_{n+1}\rangle\in Q^n$ such that $q_1<\dots<q_{n+1}=1$, and each $n$-tuple $\bar r=\langle r_1,\dots,r_n\rangle\in Q^n$ let $x(\bar q,\bar r)\in X$ be defined by $$x(\bar q,\bar r)_j=r_k\text{ iff }q_k\le j<q_{k+1}\;,$$ and let $D$ be the set of such $x(\bar q,\bar r)$. $D$ is a countable dense subset of $X$. (This or something very similar is probably the most common construction of such a set.)

For any $x,y\in D$, the set $\{|x_j-y_j|:j\in J\}$ is finite, so it has a largest member; denote that member by $d(x,y)$. It’s not hard to check that $d$ is actually a metric on $D$. To check the triangle inequality, for example, suppose that $x,y,z\in D$. Let $j\in J$ be such that $d(x,y)=|x_j-y_j|$. Then $|x_j-y_j|\le|x_j-z_j|+|z_j-y_j|\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$. Everything else is completely straightforward.

By the way, since $D$ has no isolated points, it must be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology, since up to homeomorphism that is the only countably infinite metric space without isolated points.

---

**Added:** Here’s a brief sketch of the correct argument: if $D$ is a dense subspace of $X$, $x\in D$, and $\{B_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a countable local base at $x$ in $D$, then $\{\operatorname{int}_X\operatorname{cl}_X B_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a countable local base at $x$ in $X$, since $X$ is regular. But $X$ is nowhere first countable, so $D$ must be nowhere first countable and hence cannot be metrizable. I’ll leave it to the OP to write up and accept a more detailed version if he wishes, since he really answered his own question.

Comment: I was thinking that there couldn't be a dense metrizable subset of $X$. Here is my (hopefully correct) reasoning: Every dense subset of $X$ would not be first countable. I remember seeing a proposition: If $X$ is regular and $A \subset X$ is dense and first countable, then $X$ would be first countable. So, if the Tychonoff cube had a dense first countable subset, this would imply that the Tychonoff cube would be first countable. However, the Tychonoff cube doesn't have a countable base at any point.

Comment: @josh: That proposition is false: $\beta\omega$ is a compact Hausdorff space that is very far from being first countable, but it has the countably infinite discrete space $\omega$ as a dense subset.

Comment: I realized I typed the proposition incorrectly. What I meant to say was: If $X$ is regular, $A$ is dense in $X$, and $A$ is first countable at a point $x \in A$, then $X$ is first countable at the same point $x$. This would imply if $A$ is first countable at every point, then $X$ is first countable at every point that belongs to $A$. However, $X$ may fail to be first countable at points that are not in $A$, which is shown by the $\beta \omega$ example. The Tychonoff cube doesn't have a countable base at any point, which would mean that it does not have a dense metrizable subset.

Comment: @josh: Ach, you’re quite right: I must have been asleep when I wrote that. The problem, of course, is that the metric in question doesn’t generate the product topology. Why don’t you write up the correct result, including the proof of the corrected proposition; you’ll then be able (after a day or so) to accept your own answer.